# OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to connect to **mysql** server `XAMP` in mac using python `flask-mysql`, when I run it I got this error :

> OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

I know that they are lot of similar question, I have :
`/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf` that has this line :

```
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

but when I went to :
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`

I did not see a file called :

```
mysql.sock
```

What should I do?